# Prove that $\forall i\in\Omega,\exists j\in\Omega$ such that $i\to j$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Ex: **Proposition**: Prove that  $\forall i\in\Omega,\exists j\in\Omega$ such that $i\to j$.

I know that a state $i$ leads to a state $j$, if $n\geqslant 1:P^{(n)}(i,j)>0$. $P$ stands for stochastic matrix or Markov matrix. However in the exercise there is nothing explicit about the connection of $i$ and $j$. I f I used the conditional probability I would get $P(X_1=j|X_0=i)=\frac{P(X_1=j,X_0=i)}{P(x=i)}$ If intersection is zero then $P(X_1=j|X_0=i)=0$ so $i$ would not lead to $j$ which contradicts the proposition I intended to prove.

**Question:**

How do I prove the proposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more careful about the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Let $i \in \Omega$. We know that $\sum_{j\in\Omega} P(i,j) = 1$ by definition of a stochastic matrix, hence there exists $j \in \Omega$ such that $P(i,j) > 0$ (otherwise the sum would be $0$).

Comment: How do you know the sum must not be zero? I thought if it was there would be no connection.

Comment: @PedroGomes: What is your definition of stochastic/Markov matrix?

Comment: It is a transition matrix in which a given state has certain probability to become another. But the point in my last comment was to state if the probability is zero then there is no stochastic matrix.

Comment: @PedroGomes: sorry but I don't understand your last comment. You need just check that the definition of $P$ gives the value of $\sum_{j\in\Omega} P(i,j)$.

Comment: The problem that I am going through is that the proposition does not state that there is any stochastic matrix. So there could be a stochastic matrix as you admitted but there could be none. Is it right?

Comment: @PedroGomes: as you wrote, you need a stochastic matrix to define "state $i$ leads to state $j$".

Comment: I thought the point of the proof was to show $i\to j$. I thought that was not previously assumed which would imply that the Stochastic matrix might not exist.

Comment: @PedroGomes: without any stochastic matrix, the statement does not make any sense.

Comment: That is why I think there is something lacking on the statement. Thanks for your contribution!